# Query with multiple words in any order PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've a form with multiple searchfields. One of them is for the keywords.
In the results page I'd like to build a query that allows to get multiple words in any order (i.e. "word1", "word2", "word3"  OR "word3", "word1", "word2", etc.).
I know I should use an array, and I've tried, but I haven't worked it out!
Here below my code.

Thanks!

```
    <?php
    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
    if (!$dbcnx) {
    exit('<p>Non posso connettermi al database.</p>');
    }

    if (!@mysql_select_db('xxx')) {
    exit('<p>Non posso connettermi al database.</p>');
    }

    // The basic SELECT statement
    $select = 'SELECT DISTINCT id_articolo, titolo, testo_articolo, data_articolo, categoria_id, abstract_articolo, id_categoria, categoria, link_categoria';
    $from   = ' FROM Articoli, Categoria';
    $where  = ' WHERE 1=1 AND categoria_id=id_categoria';
    $order  = ' ORDER BY data_articolo DESC';
    $aid = $_POST['aid'];
    if ($aid != '') { // An author is selected
    $where .= " AND id_autore='$aid'";
    }
    // HERE I'D LIKE TO OBTAIN A QUERY USING MULTIPLE WORDS IN ANY ORDER
    $searchtext = $_POST['searchtext'];
    if ($searchtext != '') { // Some search text was specified
    $where .= " AND testo_articolo LIKE '%$searchtext%'";
    }

    $results = @mysql_query($select . $from . $where . $order);
    if (!$results) {
    echo '</table>';
    exit('<p>Error retrieving results from database!<br />'.
    'Error: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
    }
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
  $id = $result['id_articolo'];
  $resulttext = htmlspecialchars($result['testo_articolo']);
  $titolo = $result['titolo'];
  $cat = htmlspecialchars($result['categoria']);
  $link_cat = htmlspecialchars($result['link_categoria']);
  $abstract = accorcia($result['abstract_articolo']);
  $data = convertiDataSql($result['data_articolo']);

  echo "<tr bgcolor=$color><td><a href='aticolo.php?recordID=$id'><strong style='text-transform:uppercase' class='CapitalizeSmall'>$titolo</strong></a><div style='padding-left:8px'><em>$abstract</em></div><span align='center' style='padding-left:8px' class='generale'><strong>Inserito il $data</strong> | Categoria: <a href='$link_cat' class='stile26'>$cat<a/></span><br /><br /></td></tr>\n";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't with your query construction. You're building

```
... field LIKE '%foo bar baz%'
```

which will search for the literal text `foo bar baz` in that order.

if you want "any" order, you'll have to massage the text:

```
... field LIKE '%foo%' AND field LIKE '%bar%' AND field LIKE '%baz%'
```

For this sort of thing, you'd be better off switching to a full-text index and using `match against` instead. It's designed for this kind of searching, where `LIKE '%...%'` is highly inefficient.

Plus, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).