# MySQL Full-text Search modifications, search words in any order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search, sql-like

I am using wpDataTables for a genealogy website, which has worked fantastically so far. The only hindrance is that my search filters do not return all words in that filter in a given search. For example, the string Karl Friedrich Wilhelm will return exactly that. I would like to change the coding to allow for different word ordering such as Friedrich Karl Wilhelm, etc., when words are separated by a space, they can be retrieved from the database in any order within that table column but not from the full table.

Currently, I can use the % and _ wildcards for searching without an issue. I read a little bit about full text searching, which could work, but only if it's possible to keep my use of wildcards AND get it to work with all my columns without breaking the code. (All of my SQL entries are in TEXT or VARCHAR format.) I'm not sure if a full text search would be better in this case or if a "like" statement would be more efficient (I've also read that this could open me up to [injection attacks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256269/query-with-multiple-words-in-any-order-phpmysql). I found an [article that might be of use](https://return-true.com/using-mysql-to-search-for-any-word-in-any-order/), but I have no idea how to implement it.

There are two portions to the code: the first is for a global search. I'm afraid if I alter that to do a full text search it might make queries take substantially longer, as it would search the whole table instead of the individual columns. The second is each individual filter, which on my site works for things like "Name" "Birth Place," etc.

What would I need to change about the below code to get my filters to return results in any order? You can see an example of how it currently functions on my site at http://mypomerania.com/person-search/ I'm new to using PHP with MySQL, and I haven't been able to figure out how to implement what I've read in other posts. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
            // Global search
            $search = '';
            if (!empty($_POST['search']['value'])) {
                $search = " (";
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
                    if ($_POST['columns'][$i]['searchable'] == "true") {
                        if (in_array($wdtParameters['data_types'][$_POST['columns'][$i]['name']], array('date', 'datetime', 'time'))) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            if (is_null($wdtParameters['foreignKeyRule'][$_POST['columns'][$i]['name']])) {
                                $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` LIKE '%" . addslashes($_POST['search']['value']) . "%' OR ";
                            } else {
                                $foreignKeyRule = $wdtParameters['foreignKeyRule'][$_POST['columns'][$i]['name']];
                                $joinedTable = WPDataTable::loadWpDataTable($foreignKeyRule->tableId);
                                $distinctValues = $joinedTable->getDistinctValuesForColumns($foreignKeyRule);
                                $distinctValues = array_map('strtolower', $distinctValues);

                                $filteredValues = preg_grep('~' . preg_quote(strtolower($_POST['search']['value']), '~') . '~', $distinctValues);

                                if (!empty($filteredValues)) {
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` IN (" . implode(', ', array_keys($filteredValues)) . ")  OR ";
                                } else {
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` = '" . addslashes($_POST['search']['value']) . "' OR ";
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                $search = substr_replace($search, "", -3);
                $search .= ')';
            }

            // Individual column filtering
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {

                $columnSearchFromTable = false;
                $columnSearchFromDefaultValue = false;

                if (isset($_POST['columns'][$i]['search']) &&
                    $_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'] != '' &&
                    $_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'] != '|') {
                    $columnSearchFromTable = true;
                }
                if (($_POST['draw'] == 1 || $columnSearchFromTable == true) &&
                    (isset($wdtParameters['filterDefaultValue'][$i]) &&
                    $wdtParameters['filterDefaultValue'][$i] !== '' &&
                    $wdtParameters['filterDefaultValue'][$i] !== '|' )) {
                    $columnSearchFromDefaultValue = true;
                }
                if ($_POST['columns'][$i]['searchable'] == true && ($columnSearchFromTable || $columnSearchFromDefaultValue)) {

                    //Apply placeholders when they are set in filter ​predefined value
                    $wdtParameters['filterDefaultValue'][$i]=  WDTTools::applyPlaceholders($wdtParameters['filterDefaultValue'][$i]);

                    $columnSearch = $columnSearchFromTable ? $_POST['columns'][$i]['search'][value] : $wdtParameters['filterDefaultValue'][$i];
                    if (!empty($search)) {
                        $search .= ' AND ';
                    }
                    if (isset($wdtParameters['filterTypes'][$aColumns[$i]])) {
                        switch ($wdtParameters['filterTypes'][$aColumns[$i]]) {
                            case 'number-range':
                                list($left, $right) = explode('|', $columnSearch);
                                if ($left !== '') {
                                    $left = (float)$left;
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` >= $left ";
                                }
                                if ($right !== '') {
                                    $right = (float)$right;
                                    if (!empty($search) && $left !== '') {
                                        $search .= ' AND ';
                                    }
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` <= $right ";
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'date-range':
                            case 'time-range':
                            case 'datetime-range':
                                list($left, $right) = explode('|', $columnSearch);
                                $date_format = '';
                                if ($wdtParameters['filterTypes'][$aColumns[$i]] != 'time-range') {
                                    $date_format = str_replace('m', '%m', get_option('wdtDateFormat'));
                                    $date_format = str_replace('M', '%M', $date_format);
                                    $date_format = str_replace('Y', '%Y', $date_format);
                                    $date_format = str_replace('y', '%y', $date_format);
                                    $date_format = str_replace('d', '%d', $date_format);
                                }
                                if ($wdtParameters['filterTypes'][$aColumns[$i]] == 'datetime-range'
                                    || $wdtParameters['filterTypes'][$aColumns[$i]] == 'time-range'
                                ) {
                                    $date_format .= ' ' . get_option('wdtTimeFormat');
                                    $date_format = str_replace('H', '%H', $date_format);
                                    $date_format = str_replace('h', '%h', $date_format);
                                    $date_format = str_replace('i', '%i', $date_format);
                                    $date_format = str_replace('A', '%p', $date_format);
                                }
                                if ($left && $right) {
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$left', '$date_format') AND STR_TO_DATE('$right', '$date_format') ";
                                } elseif ($left) {
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` >= STR_TO_DATE('$left', '$date_format') ";
                                } elseif ($right) {
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` <= STR_TO_DATE('$right', '$date_format') ";
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'select':
                                if ($columnSearch == 'possibleValuesAddEmpty') {
                                    $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` = '' OR `" . $aColumns[$i] . "` IS NULL";
                                } else {
                                    if ($wdtParameters['exactFiltering'][$aColumns[$i]] == 1) {
                                        $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` = '" . $columnSearch . "' ";
                                    } else {
                                        $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` LIKE '%" . $columnSearch . "%' ";
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'checkbox':
                            case 'multiselect':
                                if ($wdtParameters['exactFiltering'][$aColumns[$i]] == 1) {
                                    // Trim regex parts for first and last one
                                    if (strpos($columnSearch, '$') !== false) {
                                        $checkboxSearches = explode('$|^', $columnSearch);
                                        $checkboxSearches[0] = substr($checkboxSearches[0], 1);
                                        if (count($checkboxSearches) > 1) {
                                            $checkboxSearches[count($checkboxSearches) - 1] = substr($checkboxSearches[count($checkboxSearches) - 1], 0, -1);
                                        } else {
                                            $checkboxSearches[0] = substr($checkboxSearches[0], 0, -1);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        $checkboxSearches = explode('|', $columnSearch);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $checkboxSearches = explode('|', $columnSearch);
                                }
                                $j = 0;
                                $search .= " (";
                                foreach ($checkboxSearches as $checkboxSearch) {
                                    if ($j > 0) {
                                        $search .= " OR ";
                                    }

                                    if ($wdtParameters['exactFiltering'][$aColumns[$i]] == 1) {
                                        $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` = '" . $checkboxSearch . "' ";
                                    } else {
                                        $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` LIKE '%" . $checkboxSearch . "%' ";
                                    }

                                    $j++;
                                }
                                $search .= ") ";
                                break;
                            case 'text':
                            case 'number':
                                if (is_null($wdtParameters['foreignKeyRule'][$_POST['columns'][$i]['name']])) {
                                    if ($wdtParameters['exactFiltering'][$aColumns[$i]] == 1) {
                                        $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` = '" . $columnSearch . "' ";
                                    } else {
                                        if ($wdtParameters['filterTypes'][$aColumns[$i]] == 'number') {
                                            $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` LIKE '" . $columnSearch . "%' ";
                                        } else {
                                            $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` LIKE '%" . $columnSearch . "%' ";
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $foreignKeyRule = $wdtParameters['foreignKeyRule'][$_POST['columns'][$i]['name']];
                                    $joinedTable = WPDataTable::loadWpDataTable($foreignKeyRule->tableId);
                                    $distinctValues = $joinedTable->getDistinctValuesForColumns($foreignKeyRule);
                                    $distinctValues = array_map('strtolower', $distinctValues);

                                    if ($wdtParameters['exactFiltering'][$aColumns[$i]] == 1) {
                                        $filteredValues = preg_grep('~^' . preg_quote(strtolower($columnSearch), null) . '$~', $distinctValues);
                                    } else {
                                        $filteredValues = preg_grep('~' . preg_quote(strtolower($columnSearch), '~') . '~', $distinctValues);
                                    }

                                    if (!empty($filteredValues)) {
                                        $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` IN (" . implode(', ', array_keys($filteredValues)) . ")";
                                    } else {
                                        $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` = '" . $columnSearch . "' ";
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                $search .= '`' . $tableName . '`.`' . $aColumns[$i] . "` LIKE '%" . $columnSearch . "%' ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($search) {
                $search = 'WHERE ' . $search;
                $parsedSearch = $parser->parse($search);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Provided a proper index, a query using `LIKE` can take advantage of the index if the wildcard is appended to the parameter like `something%`, but not so for `%something`. Just try the full text search, or take a look at sphinx or elasticsearch.

Comment: I don't know how to implement that with the code I have.